# Fragment in viewpager makes an error

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

Hi i'm a novice programmer. Making an android app, I faced error when i have tested my own app. I have made filter text to search keywords in database. Filter text works quite well, but AfterTextChanged method makes a null pointer exception error in fragment of viewpager.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
ek.cert4u.Study$1.afterTextChanged(Study.java:196)
android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7424)
android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3822)
android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)                                             android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
```

How can i remove these error from my app?

It's the code of ek.cert4u.Study

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b){
        super.onActivityCreated(b);
        NestedScrollView mScollView = (NestedScrollView) getView().findViewById(R.id.mScrollView4);
        MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerScrollView(getActivity(), mScollView);

        editText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.studyFilter);
        recommendedStudyListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.StudyList);
        recommendedStudyListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String filterText = s.toString();
                ((RecommendedStudyListAdapter) recommendedStudyListView.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(filterText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You need to show us your `Study.java:196`

Comment: ((RecommendedStudyListAdapter) recommendedStudyListView.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(filterText);

Comment: Sorry for omitting the code :( It is a Study.java:196

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], not one line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set an adapter on the recommendedStudyListView so getAdapter() returns null

Comment: Thanks. It was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `onViewCreated` instead of `onActivityCreated`

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    NestedScrollView mScollView = (NestedScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.mScrollView4);
    MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerScrollView(getActivity(), mScollView);

    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.studyFilter);
    recommendedStudyListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.StudyList);
    recommendedStudyListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    RecommendedStudyListAdapter adapter = new RecommendedStudyListAdapter(.............);
    recommendedStudyListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String filterText = s.toString();
            ((RecommendedStudyListAdapter) recommendedStudyListView.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(filterText);
        }
    });

}
```

i guess this

```
((RecommendedStudyListAdapter) recommendedStudyListView.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(filterText);
```

makes your fragment crash because you dont set any adapter in your fragment

Answer (score 0):

According to the lifecycle of the fragment we should use

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);
}
```

for all the view initialisation.